# How can WebApi ChallengeResult be incorporated into an Angular2 SPA?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**Context**

We are migrating a web application using Asp.Net Core (Web Api) to use an Angular2 
 Single Page Application (SPA) front end. The application was initially made with "Individual User Accounts". We have been converting the cshtml views to Angular2 components, the controller methods to produce Json, even incorporating JWT for authentication.

I have been using this [Configuring Google authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins) microsoft documentation.

**Problem**

The issue is illustrated by the following two controller methods. The `LinkLogin` method returns a `ChallengeResult` action. Obviously this cannot be converted to JSON. I *presume* this result is supposed to cause the browser to redirect to the external login provider, then automatically redirect to `LinkLoginCallback`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LinkLogin([FromBody] string provider)
    {
        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(externalCookieScheme);

        // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
        string redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(LinkLoginCallback), "Manage");
        var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, userManager.GetUserId(User));
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
    {
        User user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
            return Json(false);

        ExternalLoginInfo info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(await userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
        if (info == null)
            return Json(false);

        IdentityResult result = await userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(externalCookieScheme);
            return Json(true);
        }

        return Json(false);
    }
```

If I do attempt to call `LinkLogin` from Angular I get this response:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53462' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: Have you configured CORS ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Comment: There is services.AddCors(); however no app.UseCors(); I will see what it does if it uses it.

Comment: Does not work. I have added `[EnableCors("ExternalLoginPolicy")]` to both controller method. I then added the origin 'https://accounts.google.com' to the policy configuration.

Comment: Do I just need to add the header the thrown error has shown in my initial request to LinkLogin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up coming up with a solution that avoids "ChallengeResult" by modifying the flow between Angular2 and the WebApi.

1. Added the `angular2-social-login` npm package to the angular app (following all their [easy instructions for setup](https://github.com/heresy/angular2-social-login)).
2. Merged both controller methods into one. The `ExternalLoginViewModel` parameter is a simple class with Email, ProviderKey and LoginProvider properties (populated in Angular in step 3):

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [Produces("application/json")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLogin([FromBody] ExternalLoginViewModel info)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           User user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
           if (user != null)
           {
               IdentityResult result = await userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, new UserLoginInfo(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, info.LoginProvider));
               if (result.Succeeded)
                   return Json(true);
           }
       }
       return Json(false);
   }
   ```
3. Changed the Angular2 client to use the social media package to get the credentials needed for the web api. Here is my `LinkProvider` method demonstrating the connection: (`this.service.LinkLogin` calls the `LinkLogin` controller method)

   ```
   public async LinkProvider(providerName: string): Promise<void>
   {
       const result: any = await this.auth.login(providerName).toPromise();
       const success: boolean = await this.service.LinkLogin({
            email: result.email,
            loginProvider: result.provider,
            providerKey: result.uid
       });

       // Handle link response here
   }
   ```